# Does open-circuit voltage decrease when resistance increases in a solar cell?

Tags: electricity, temperature, potential, photoelectric-effect, solar-cells

In a solar cell, if resistance were to somehow increase (maybe heating up the panel), would that contribute in any meaningful way in decreasing the open-circuit voltage?

Comment: Is current flowing under open circuit conditions?

Comment: @JonCuster There are photocurrent and forward current being generated that cancel out. There is no net current flowing in the circuit.

Comment: No, there are photo-generated carriers and recombination. There is no forward current without an applied forward bias.